# Select random post every day

Tags: wp-query

I am looking for a script to select 1 random post per day in Wordpress.
I found the code below, but this keeps gathering a new post every time I refresh the page:

```
 <?php
function force_random_day_seed($orderby) {
    $seed = floor( time() / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    $orderby=str_replace('RAND()', "RAND({$seed})", $orderby);
    return $orderby;
}
        add_filter('posts_orderby', 'force_random_day_seed');
$args = array('numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'listing');
$totd = get_posts($args);
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'force_random_day_seed');
foreach( $totd as $post ) : ?> 
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `posts_orderby` filter is not available for  `get_posts()` where `suppress_filters` is `true` by default.

You can use `WP_Query` instead:

```
$args = [ 
    'posts_per_page'      => 1, 
    'orderby'             => 'rand', 
    'post_type'           => 'listing', 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
];

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'force_random_day_seed' );
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'force_random_day_seed' );

if( $q->have_posts() )
{
    while( $q->have_posts() )
    {
        $q->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else
{
    _e( 'Sorry no posts found!' );
}
```

It's also possible to skip your `posts_orderby` filter callback and just use [transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to store the results for 24 hours.

Comment: tried to implement but multiple things go wrong. please further elaborate.

Comment: What do you mean by "go wrong"? Are you getting PHP syntax error?

Comment: Hi, first of all i changed the `args = [` to an array like `args= array(...);` Is that correct? Further, it wont gather any post content. It breaks down my site. (loads nothing and template gets broken). Thanks

Comment: ok so you're using an old PHP version (<5.4). yes then you use `array()` instead of `[]`. Always develop with `WP_DEBUG` as `TRUE` so you can see what type of errors. I just used `the_title()` for simplification, you can add `the_content()` as well. This seems to work on the default theme. @RobbertT

Comment: Thanks. It does work with the [ ]. Dreamweaver was saying it was a syntax error, but my host accepts it. Thanks!

Comment: @RobberT your dreamweaver is a dinosaur. Old versions throws an error on the new short array syntax. This feature was introduced in PHP 5.4, which your dreamwaever is not geared up for. You should upgrade your dreamwaever to bring it up to par :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code:-

```
 <?php
    function force_random_day_seed($orderby) {
        $seed = floor( time() / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
        $orderby=str_replace('RAND()', "RAND({$seed})", $orderby);
        return $orderby;
    }
            add_filter('posts_orderby', 'force_random_day_seed');
$temp_value = get_option(current_time('Y-m-d'));
if($temp_value == '' ){
    $args = array('numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'listing');
    $totd = get_posts($args);
foreach($totd as $k=>$v){
update_option(current_time('Y-m-d'),$v->ID);
}
}else{
$totd = get_posts($temp_value);
}
    remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'force_random_day_seed');
    foreach( $totd as $post ) : ?> 
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this however just gets 5 posts that are normal posts instead of the 'listing' post_type. So guess something goes wrong.